# MongoDb query not functioning as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My query doesn't works. I don't know why.

I want to get the messages at the return, to add some more messages to this same conversation.

I'm new at all of this stuffs, mongoDb and node.

Query

```js
  const query = {
    $and: [
      { member1: { $in: [conversation.sender, conversation.receiver] } },
      { member2: { $in: [conversation.sender, conversation.receiver] } }
    ],
  };
  const response = await Conversation.distinct('timestamps', query).exec();
```

Here's the database object that i'm tryin to find in this query, the result is empty and no errors are shown.

database:

```js
{
    "members": [{
        "member1": "5e87f879ac23bb2018be0e73",
        "member2": "5e87e6144da131247407194f",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5e88112190e6de5e4826d758"
        }
    }],
    "messages": [{
        "sender": "5e87f879ac23bb2018be0e73",
        "receiver": "5e87e6144da131247407194f",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5e88112190e6de5e4826d75a"
        },
        "message": "Cria vergonha",
        "messageAddAt": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1585975585995"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "sender": "5e87e6144da131247407194f",
        "receiver": "5e87f879ac23bb2018be0e73",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5e88112190e6de5e4826d759"
        },
        "message": "Cria vergonha",
        "messageAddAt": {
            "$date": {
                "$numberLong": "1585975585996"
            }
        }
    }],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1585975586070"
        }
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1585975586070"
        }
    },
    "__v": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    }
}
```

I've tested it in Robo 3T and it works!

```js
db.conversations.find(
{$and: [
      { "members.member1": { $in: ['5e87e6144da131247407194f', '5e87f879ac23bb2018be0e73'] } },
      { "members.member2": { $in: ['5e87e6144da131247407194f', '5e87f879ac23bb2018be0e73'] } }
    ]})
```

But at node.js, it brigs nothing as result.

Comment: `const conversation = await Conversations.findOne({
              $and: [
                { users: { $in: [users[0]] } },
                { users: { $in: [users[1]] } }
              ]
            });`

Comment: did you try this code? Instead of distinct, use findOne or findMany
Also can you make you clear what results are you expecting?

Comment: Yes, i already used some but as always, it returns nothing.

Comment: There is no `timestamps` field in your document; but you are trying the `distinct` operation on it.

Comment: To query on multiple fields of a sub-document in an array (i.e., `members` array and fields `member1` and `member2`) use `$elemMatch` _query operator_: [Specify Multiple Conditions for Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/index.html#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents). Also, see this [example code](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/reference/ecmascriptnext/crud/) of using the `find` query in NodeJS using `async-await` construct.